# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Below is my stored procedure, but upon executing it the following error occured:

> Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ACEsp_AuditInvoice, Line 84
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement
>   contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Please review my stored procedure, and tell me how I will avoid the error above.
Thanks in advance

```
USE [FAC]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ACEsp_AuditInvoice]    Script Date: 10/18/2012 09:26:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      Ryan
-- Create date: 18 Oct 2012

-- version: 12.10
-- Description: Originated from ACEsp_InvVsListPrice, modified for invoice auditing 
-- parameter by date, month and year
-- Additional 10 columns for invoice auditing
-- =============================================

--[dbo].[ACEsp_AuditInvoice] '2012-09-17','2012-09-17','SEPTEMBER','2012'

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ACEsp_AuditInvoice] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @dtfrom datetime,
    @dtto datetime,
    @MNTH varchar(12),
    @YR INT
    --@prcMakro varchar(15)
WITH RECOMPILE

AS

create table #brand (
    [CODE] [char](15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [IVBRAND] [char](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL 
)

create table #SubCat (
    [CODE] [char](15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
    [IVSUBCAT] [char](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL    
)

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SDFROM VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @SDTO VARCHAR(20)

    SET @SDFROM = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DTFROM, 101) + ' 00:00:00'
    SET @DTFROM = CAST(@SDFROM AS DATETIME)

    SET @SDTO = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DTTO, 101) + ' 23:59:59'
    SET @DTTO = CAST(@SDTO AS DATETIME)


    insert into #brand
    select USCATVAL, Image_URL
    from IV40600
    where USCATNUM = 2

    insert into #SubCat
    select USCATVAL, Image_URL
    from IV40600
    where USCATNUM = 4

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select 'posted' as Trx, d.quantity, d.qtytoinv, d.qtycance, (d.qtytoinv - d.qtyfulfi) 'qtyfulfivar', 
        (u.equomqty * d.qtyfulfi) 'qtybaseuom', 
        (d.XTNDPRCE - 
        (d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty) *       
            isnull(p.psitmval, 
                ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                        AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                )) 'variance',

        CASE(d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty) *       
            isnull(p.psitmval, 
                ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                        AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                )
            WHEN 0 THEN 0
            ELSE
            (d.XTNDPRCE /  
            ((d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty) *      
            isnull(p.psitmval, 
                ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                        AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                )))-1
            end as 'percentvar',

        p.PRCSHID, h.docdate, h.bachnumb, h.ReqShipDate,
        d.lnitmseq, d.locncode,  d.UNITPRCE, 
        p.psitmval as [LIST PRICE], i.stndcost, d.qtybsuom, c.slprsnid, sp.slprsnfn, 
        sp.sprsnsln, c.salsterr, st.slterdsc, h.custnmbr, h.custname, 
        c.shrtname as 'CUSTOGROUP', c.custclas as 'CUSTOCLAS', c2.ZIP as 'CHANSEG',
        h.sopnumbe, d.itemnmbr, d.itemdesc, 
        case i.itemtype
            WHEN 1 THEN 'SALES INVENTORY'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'DISCONTINUED'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'KITS'
        end as 'ITEMTYPE',
        d.qtyfulfi, d.uofm, d.XTNDPRCE, u.equivuom 'BASEUOM', u.equomqty 'PACKING', 
        d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty 'bqty',

        isnull( (SELECT TOP 1 LISTPRICE FROM tbl_disco_historical_baseuom HH  WHERE HH.ITEMNMBR = D.ITEMNMBR AND HH.BASEUOM = U2.BASEUOFM AND HH.LEFFECTDATE >= H.DOCDATE ORDER BY HH.LEFFECTDATE DESC),
            isnull(p.psitmval, 
                    ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                            WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                            AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                            AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                        AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                    )) as 'BASE PRICE – LIST PRICE PER BUOM',

        isnull(p.psitmval*d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty,
                    ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                         WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                         AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                         AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM ), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                * d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty
               )
                AS 'EXTND PRICE by BASE PRICE-BUOM',    
        p1.psitmval as 'MAKRO PRICE – LIST PRICE', 
        p1.psitmval*d.qtyfulfi as 'EXTND PRICE BY MAKRO',
        d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty AS 'QTYBASEUOM', 
        ISNULL(
        (SELECT TOP 1 LISTPRICE FROM tbl_disco_historical_baseuom HH  WHERE HH.ITEMNMBR = D.ITEMNMBR AND HH.BASEUOM = U2.BASEUOFM AND HH.LEFFECTDATE >= H.DOCDATE ORDER BY HH.LEFFECTDATE DESC),
        isnull(p.psitmval, 
                ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                        AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                ))
                as 'BaseUomListPrice',

            (d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty) *       
            isnull(p.psitmval, 
                ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                        AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                )           
                as 'BaseUomTotalListPrice', 

        (d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty) *       
            isnull(p.psitmval, 
                ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                        AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                ) - D.XTNDPRCE AS 'TOTAL DISCOUNT',
            a.IVBRAND as 'BRAND', b.IVSUBCAT as 'SubCat',
            dbo.ACEfunc_CUSTOTYPE2(c.CUSTCLAS,c.SALSTERR) AS 'CUSTTYPE', D.MRKDNAMT*d.qtyfulfi AS 'MARKDOWN',
            cast(i.uscatvls_6 as float) as 'ITEM REPORT SEQUENCE',
            rtrim(ltrim(cast(uscatvls_1 as varchar(4)))) + '-' + bh.image_url as 'BRAND HANDLER',
            I.ITMCLSCD 'ITEM CLASS', d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty/uu.equomqty AS 'CASEQTY',
            ii.inet1 as 'ABC CAT',
            ISNULL(APL.PCPRICE,isnull(p.psitmval, 
                    ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                            WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                            AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                            AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                        AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                    )) as 'APL(SAG) Piece Price', h.docid as 'SOP TYPE ID'

    from sop30200 h
        inner join sop30300 d on (h.sopnumbe = d.sopnumbe)
        inner join IV00101 i on (d.itemnmbr = i.itemnmbr)
        inner join RM00101 c on (h.custnmbr = c.custnmbr)
        left join RM00102 c2 on (c.custnmbr = c2.custnmbr and c2.adrscode = 'MAIN')
        left join RM00301 sp on (sp.slprsnid = c.slprsnid)
        left join RM00303 st on (st.salsterr = c.salsterr)
        LEFT JOIN iv40202 u on (i.uomschdl = u.uomschdl and d.uofm = u.uofm and u.qtybsuom <> 0)
        LEFT JOIN iv40201 u2 on (i.uomschdl = u2.uomschdl)
        left join iv10402 p1 on (d.itemnmbr = p1.itemnmbr and p1.PRCSHID = 'PLMAKRO'
            and d.uofm = p1.uofm)
        left join iv10402 p on (d.itemnmbr = p.itemnmbr and p.PRCSHID = 'BASE PRICE'
            and U.EQUIVUOM = p.uofm)
        left join #brand a on (i.uscatvls_2 = a.code)
        left join #SubCat b on (i.uscatvls_4 = b.code)
        left join iv40600 bh on (i.uscatvls_1 = bh.uscatval AND bh.uscatnum = 1)
        left join iv40202 uu on (i.uomschdl = uu.uomschdl and i.selnguom = uu.uofm and uu.qtybsuom <> 0)
        LEFT join sy01200 as ii on (ii.master_id = d.itemnmbr and ii.master_type = 'ITM') 
        LEFT JOIN T0_APL APL ON (D.ITEMNMBR=APL.ITEMNMBR AND APL.MNTH = @MNTH AND APL.YR = @YR)

UNION ALL

    select 'unposted' as Trx, d.quantity, d.qtytoinv, d.qtycance, (d.qtytoinv - d.qtyfulfi) 'qtyfulfivar', 
        (u.equomqty * d.qtyfulfi) 'qtybaseuom', 
        (d.XTNDPRCE - 
        (d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty) *       
            isnull(p.psitmval, 
                ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                        AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                )) 'variance',

        CASE(d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty) *       
            isnull(p.psitmval, 
                ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                        AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                )
            WHEN 0 THEN 0
            ELSE
            (d.XTNDPRCE /  
            ((d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty) *      
            isnull(p.psitmval, 
                ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                        AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                )))-1
            end as 'percentvar',

        p.PRCSHID, h.docdate, h.bachnumb, h.ReqShipDate,
        d.lnitmseq, d.locncode,  d.UNITPRCE, 
        p.psitmval as [LIST PRICE], i.stndcost, d.qtybsuom, c.slprsnid, sp.slprsnfn, 
        sp.sprsnsln, c.salsterr, st.slterdsc, h.custnmbr, h.custname, 
        c.shrtname as 'CUSTOGROUP', c.custclas as 'CUSTOCLAS', c2.ZIP as 'CHANSEG',
        h.sopnumbe, d.itemnmbr, d.itemdesc, 
        case i.itemtype
            WHEN 1 THEN 'SALES INVENTORY'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'DISCONTINUED'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'KITS'
        end as 'ITEMTYPE',
        d.qtyfulfi, d.uofm, d.XTNDPRCE, u.equivuom 'BASEUOM', u.equomqty 'PACKING', 
        d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty 'bqty',

        isnull( (SELECT TOP 1 LISTPRICE FROM tbl_disco_historical_baseuom HH  WHERE HH.ITEMNMBR = D.ITEMNMBR AND HH.BASEUOM = U2.BASEUOFM AND HH.LEFFECTDATE >= H.DOCDATE ORDER BY HH.LEFFECTDATE DESC),
            isnull(p.psitmval, 
                    ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                            WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                            AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                            AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                        AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                    )) as 'BASE PRICE – LIST PRICE PER BUOM',

        isnull(p.psitmval*d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty,
                    ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                         WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                         AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                         AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM ), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                * d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty
               )
                AS 'EXTND PRICE by BASE PRICE-BUOM',    
        p1.psitmval as 'MAKRO PRICE – LIST PRICE', 
        p1.psitmval*d.qtyfulfi as 'EXTND PRICE BY MAKRO',
        d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty AS 'QTYBASEUOM', 
        ISNULL(
        (SELECT TOP 1 LISTPRICE FROM tbl_disco_historical_baseuom HH  WHERE HH.ITEMNMBR = D.ITEMNMBR AND HH.BASEUOM = U2.BASEUOFM AND HH.LEFFECTDATE >= H.DOCDATE ORDER BY HH.LEFFECTDATE DESC),
        isnull(p.psitmval, 
                ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                        AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                ))
                as 'BaseUomListPrice',

            (d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty) *       
            isnull(p.psitmval, 
                ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                        AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                )           
                as 'BaseUomTotalListPrice', 

        (d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty) *       
            isnull(p.psitmval, 
                ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                        AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                    WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                    AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                    AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                ) - D.XTNDPRCE AS 'TOTAL DISCOUNT',
            a.IVBRAND as 'BRAND', b.IVSUBCAT as 'SubCat',
            dbo.ACEfunc_CUSTOTYPE2(c.CUSTCLAS,c.SALSTERR) AS 'CUSTTYPE', D.MRKDNAMT*d.qtyfulfi AS 'MARKDOWN',
            cast(i.uscatvls_6 as float) as 'ITEM REPORT SEQUENCE',
            rtrim(ltrim(cast(uscatvls_1 as varchar(4)))) + '-' + bh.image_url as 'BRAND HANDLER',
            I.ITMCLSCD 'ITEM CLASS', d.qtyfulfi*u.equomqty/uu.equomqty AS 'CASEQTY',
            ii.inet1 as 'ABC CAT',
            ISNULL(APL.PCPRICE,isnull(p.psitmval, 
                    ISNULL((SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                            WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                            AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                            AND UOFM = U.EQUIVUOM), (SELECT psitmval from iv10402 
                                                        WHERE prcShid = 'BASE PRICE' 
                                                        AND itemnmbr = d.itemnmbr 
                                                        AND UOFM = D.UOFM))
                    )) as 'APL(SAG) Piece Price', h.docid as 'SOP TYPE ID'

    from sop10100 h
        inner join sop10200 d on (h.sopnumbe = d.sopnumbe)
        inner join IV00101 i on (d.itemnmbr = i.itemnmbr)
        inner join RM00101 c on (h.custnmbr = c.custnmbr)
        left join RM00102 c2 on (c.custnmbr = c2.custnmbr and c2.adrscode = 'MAIN')
        left join RM00301 sp on (sp.slprsnid = c.slprsnid)
        left join RM00303 st on (st.salsterr = c.salsterr)
        LEFT JOIN iv40202 u on (i.uomschdl = u.uomschdl and d.uofm = u.uofm and u.qtybsuom <> 0)
        LEFT JOIN iv40201 u2 on (i.uomschdl = u2.uomschdl)
        left join iv10402 p1 on (d.itemnmbr = p1.itemnmbr and p1.PRCSHID = 'PLMAKRO'
            and d.uofm = p1.uofm)
        left join iv10402 p on (d.itemnmbr = p.itemnmbr and p.PRCSHID = 'BASE PRICE'
            and U.EQUIVUOM = p.uofm)
        left join #brand a on (i.uscatvls_2 = a.code)
        left join #SubCat b on (i.uscatvls_4 = b.code)
        left join iv40600 bh on (i.uscatvls_1 = bh.uscatval AND bh.uscatnum = 1)
        left join iv40202 uu on (i.uomschdl = uu.uomschdl and i.selnguom = uu.uofm and uu.qtybsuom <> 0)
        LEFT join sy01200 as ii on (ii.master_id = d.itemnmbr and ii.master_type = 'ITM') 
        LEFT JOIN T0_APL APL ON (D.ITEMNMBR=APL.ITEMNMBR AND APL.MNTH = @MNTH AND APL.YR = @YR)     

    where
        h.soptype = 3 and d.CMPNTSEQ = 0 and h.voidstts = 0 and h.pstgstus = 2
        and h.docdate >= @DTFROM and h.docdate <= @DTTO
    --order by percentvar, h.custname, d.sopnumbe, d.itemnmbr

END
```

Comment: Hi! I already commented out the order by. The error does not display, but upon executing it, the query seems to hang. Upon separating the 2 select statements without UNION ALL, the query is working fine. Can you help me how to combine the two select statements using UNION ALL? Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a different question.  If the two queries run OK independently, and they are returning the same columns, the UNION ALL should work.  Is it definitely the Select that's hanging?  What happens if you run it independently?

Comment: It work fine upon running it independently. Do you think the error is on the temporary table that I used? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I already fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ORDER BY` statement in your query you have to mention that in the select list of your query. For example I have given you the link. If you go through it you will get an idea to use the `ORDER BY` clause in SQL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx

Comment: Hi! I already commented out the order by. The error does not display, but upon executing it, the query seems to hang. Upon separating the 2 select statements without UNION ALL, the query is working fine. Can you help me how to combine the two select statements using UNION ALL? Thanks

Comment: -1 No you don't. For example, `SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ORDER BY TABLE_NAME` works just fine.

Comment: @ta.speot.is c i have given you the link to learn the order by clause.In some situation the limitations are to be considered.it will work fine for a simple query like what you given above.read the site properly and understand it.

Comment: The link does not support your claim that *you have to mention that in the select list of your query*. You **don't** have to. The wording from the link is *The column names referenced in the ORDER BY clause must correspond to either a column in the select list **or to a column defined in a table specified in the FROM clause** without any ambiguities.*

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting h.sopnumbe, but ordering by d.sopnumbe

Try changing the order by to use h.sopnumbe

Comment: Hi! I already commented out the order by. The error does not display, but upon executing it, the query seems to hang. Upon separating the 2 select statements without UNION ALL, the query is working fine. Can you help me how to combine the two select statements using UNION ALL? Thanks